# How to add System.Windows.Forms In .net6.0 or later Windows Presentation Foundation(WPF) Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-6.0

Adding System.Windows.Forms but it can not add it.

how to get windows forms functionality in Windows Presentation Foundation(WPF) Application?

Here in .net 6.0+ version can not give directly support to add this functionality.